# Attaching a queryset-to-csv file in a django mail

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to attach this csv file that's created by the library `django-queryset-csv` ([see docs](https://pypi.org/project/django-queryset-csv/)), but when I recieve and open the file in my inbox, it's just empty.

```
mail = EmailMessage(subject, text, from_email, [to])
with open(f'Orders for {date.today().strftime("%b-%d-%Y")}.csv', 'wb+') as f:
       write_csv(todays_orders, f)
       mail.attach(f.name, f.read())
mail.send()
```

The csv is being created properly (it's located in the same directory as `manage.py`), but it won't get attached. I think it is because I'm accessing it wrong by calling `f.name` and `f.read()`.

How can I get the file that I've just created in order to attach it and send it?

Comment: Have you tried doing mail.attach_file('path_to_csv') instead?

Comment: Just tried it, but it's still empty... very strange

Comment: Try doing the mail.attach outside of the context manager, maybe it's attaching before the CSV is actually ready

Comment: Yes, but in that case how can I get the name of the file? I cannot call `f.read` anymore

Comment: Nevermind, it's the same thing :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: hey add one more parameter f.content_type then check

Comment: It worked fine with the last advice. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mail.set_content()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) method from EmailMessage object

```
mail = EmailMessage(subject, text, from_email, [to])
filename_csv = f'Orders for {date.today().strftime("%b-%d-%Y")}.csv'
with open(filename_csv, 'wb+') as f:
       write_csv(todays_orders, f)
       mail.set_content(f.read())

mail.send()
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO and thank you for investing time to post an answer. But it is recommended to add an explanation to your answer.